# -[%s applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283c1cc40

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have an iOS specific problem related to Flutter and Unity. I'm using the [Unity Flutter Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) to add Augmented Reality to my app.

It works perfectly on Android phones, iPads and newer iPhones but whenever I launch it on an older iPhone, the app crash 50% of the time after loading Unity. I was able to find the following error in the crash log:

`Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Reason: -[%s applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283c1cc40 Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6 Terminating Process: Runner [2868]`

Appearantly someone else encountered [the same error](https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget/issues/842) about a month ago but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

I don't even know where to begin with this problem because I am fairly new to mobile app development. If anyone knows how I can tackle this, please let me know. :)

Comment: Your app is using too much memory. This will vary by device and OS version but generally if you hit 50% of the device memory your app will be killed.